# Git merge master into remote tracked feature branch

Tags: git, sourcetree

My team recently converted from Using Perforce to Git for source control.  One question I cannot find a good answer on is how to properly integrate changes changes from origin:master into my feature branch that is origin tracked (two developers are making commits into the branch).

I tried to perform a Merge from master, but then I see a merge commit that shows all of the files I have modified in the current branch.  Is this expected?

Note that my team is using SourceTree instead of command line.

Comment: Yes, merge creates a new commit with two parents, _merging_ the histories of both branches. If the same files changed in both branches, you'll see this commit modified those files, by importing the other branch's changes.

Comment: This is a true merge or a non fast forward merge. To merge BranchA to BranchB introduces all the commits of BranchA into BranchB. If BranchB's head is an ancestor of BranchA's head, a fast forward merge is made instead. The option `--no-ff` can always resolve the merge as a true merge even if it's the fast forward case. If you need only some of the commits of BranchA, you could use `git cherry-pick` or `git merge` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the feature branch is used by multiple members of your team `merge` is the best option, in other cases I prefer use `rebase`.

Merge are fast-forward (`--ff`) by default and whenever it is possible, in case of not (conflits, etc) they will be not fast forwarded (`--no-ff`).

When are not fast-forwarded they produce an additional merge-commit (like in your case) with a message informing us about the merged branch (and parents commits refs).

Some [people](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (and tools like [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/#merging-a-pull-request-using-the-github-web-interface)) prefer force `--no-ff` merges for readability and clarity of git logs.